# Firebase removing data that belongs to a user

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Given I have a uid and every record with be stored under a different object that is contained within a uid, is there a way to delete all records belonging to that uid without having to individually reference each object (departments, stores...assuming this list will grow much larger)?

My database is constructed like so

```
users
  uid
departments
  uid
    $departmentId
      deptName
      active
stores
  uid
    $storeId
      storeName
      active
```

Comment: you need to describe a little better so we can understand what you are asking. Keep in mind that your question will be later used as refference for other users and your question should be easy to understand. You can start adding some screenshots of your database tree.

Comment: @adolfosrs please don't ask for a *screenshot* of the JSON tree. A screenshot of text is a sad substitute for the text proper. The actual JSON as text can easily be gotten by clicking the Export button in the Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.:-)

Comment: @SeanCook: that sounds entirely doable. What have you already tried? What are you having problems with? What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, you need to structure your db like this

```
 users
  uid
   departments
     deptName
     Active
   stores
     storeName
     Active
```

So when you delete a user all of the user info will also be deleted. You need to think of how you want to build your database and what kind of info you want the userprofile to have.

Comment: I actually found out how to use your format but separate the user information so I only allow read access on the deeper nests which solved my issue with your approach. Thank You!

Comment: no problem, just remember that if you want to store any information to a user always go for this approach. glad it helped